# Airflow SendEmail operator unexpected failure

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm trying to use the EmailOperator in my Airflow DAG.
I have both SES and SNMP configurations in place, but I'm not even able to verify the config is working, due to the below error.

email config:

```
[email]
email_backend = airflow.providers.amazon.aws.utils.emailer.send_email
email_conn_id = {{ AIRFLOW_CONN_AWS_DEFAULT}}
smtp_host = email-smtp.{{ AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }}.amazonaws.com
smtp_starttls = True
smtp_ssl = False
smtp_port = 587
```

This is how the operator is defined:

```
import datetime
import os

import airflow
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.email import EmailOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from operators.factory import AirflowDAGFactory, kubernetes_pod_operator_factory
from operators.shared import (
    AIRFLOW_POD_TYPE,
    AIRFLOW_TASK_NAME,
    DAG_TASK_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_HOURS,
    DEFAULT_POD_RESOURCES,
    DOCKER_REGISTRY,
    ENV_NAME,
    ENV_TYPE,
    EXECUTOR_POD,
    FLOW_NAME,
    K8S_EXECUTOR_CONFIG,
    STEPS_VERSION_DICT,
    WORKER_POD,
)

dag_interval = datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)

flow_name = "airflow_health"

DEFAULT_POD_ARGS = {
    "owner": "Airflow",
    "start_date": airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
    "namespace": os.environ.get("NAMESPACE", f"pai-{ENV_TYPE}-{ENV_NAME}"),
    "get_logs": True,
    "in_cluster": True,
    "log_events_on_failure": True,
    "service_account_name": f"airflow-service-account-{ENV_NAME}",
    "startup_timeout_seconds": 600,
    "retry_delay": os.environ.get("RETRY_DELAY", 30),
    "executor_config": {"KubernetesExecutor": K8S_EXECUTOR_CONFIG},
    "reattach_on_restart": False,
    "labels": {AIRFLOW_POD_TYPE: EXECUTOR_POD},
    "execution_timeout": datetime.timedelta(hours=DAG_TASK_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_HOURS),
}


dag = AirflowDAGFactory.airflow_dag(
    dag_id="airflow_health_dag",
    catchup=False,
    default_args=DEFAULT_POD_ARGS,
    schedule_interval=dag_interval,
    max_active_runs=1,
)


airflow_health = kubernetes_pod_operator_factory(
    image=f"{DOCKER_REGISTRY}/airflow-health:{STEPS_VERSION_DICT['airflow-health']}",
    name="airflow_health",
    task_id="airflow-health",
    env_vars={
        "ENV_NAME": ENV_NAME,
        "ENV_TYPE": ENV_TYPE,
        "FLOW_NAME": flow_name,
    },
    resources=DEFAULT_POD_RESOURCES,
    dag=dag,
    labels={AIRFLOW_TASK_NAME: "airflow-health", FLOW_NAME: flow_name, AIRFLOW_POD_TYPE: WORKER_POD},
    is_delete_operator_pod=False,
)


def print_context(ds, **kwargs):
    """
    Some random function that prints the context
    """
    print(kwargs)
    print(ds)
    return "Whatever you return gets printed in the logs"


sample_python_operator = PythonOperator(
    task_id="print_the_context",
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=print_context,
    dag=dag,
)

# email_status = EmailOperator(
#     to="me@company.com",
#     subject="Test from SES",
#     html_content="Trying to send an email from airflow through SES.",
#     task_id="sending_status_email",
#     dag=dag,
# )

# workaround in order to be able to set the dag to failed (and still have the final_status_step succeed)
mark_dag_failed = DummyOperator(task_id="mark-failed", dag=dag)

# airflow_health >> sample_python_operator >> email_status >> mark_dag_failed
airflow_health >> sample_python_operator >> mark_dag_failed
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
 [2022-03-13 16:13:00,086] {standard_task_runner.py:88} ERROR - Failed to execute job 8352 for task sending_status_email                                                                     
 Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                          
   File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/task/task_runner/standard_task_runner.py", line 85, in _start_by_fork                                                           
     args.func(args, dag=self.dag)                                                                                                                                                           
   File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 48, in command                                                                                         
     return func(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                            
   File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 92, in wrapper                                                                                              
     return f(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                               
   File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 292, in task_run                                                                            
     _run_task_by_selected_method(args, dag, ti)                                                                                                                                             
   File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 107, in _run_task_by_selected_method                                                        
     _run_raw_task(args, ti)                                                                                                                                                                 
   File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 180, in _run_raw_task                                                                       
     ti._run_raw_task(                                                                                                                                                                       
   File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 70, in wrapper                                                                                          
     return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                           
   File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1332, in _run_raw_task                                                                            
     self._execute_task_with_callbacks(context)                                                                                                                                              
   File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1458, in _execute_task_with_callbacks                                                             
     result = self._execute_task(context, self.task)                                                                                                                                         
   File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1509, in _execute_task                                                                            
     result = execute_callable(context=context)                                                                                                                                              
   File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/email.py", line 79, in execute                                                                                        
     send_email(                                                                                                                                                                             
   File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 55, in send_email                                                                                         
     return backend(                                                                                                                                                                         
 TypeError: send_email() missing 1 required positional argument: 'html_content'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. Are you sure the code you posted is the real code?

Comment: Yes, It's the real code

Comment: I've updated it to contain the full DAG (the problematic code is currently commented out)

Comment: How did you configure SES?

Comment: Ah, I think I see the problem.
I'm using `airflow.providers.amazon.aws.utils.emailer.send_email` as the email backend, but it expects the html_content to be the 4th parameter.

Comment: Order doesnt matter when using name arguments

Comment: did you fix this? i am having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem and according to code
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/6e269570cd6dd2d434a3c63ca0db9f1a59dea847/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L1281

Suppose without provided template, a default content should be used for email content. But no sure why it reported error for no html_content

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the issue you're encountering is related to a bug in **apache-airflow-providers-amazon==2.4.0**. You can find more details about this bug in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/21671). There's yet [another issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16778) connected with it, so my answer will address both.

To address this problem, there are a couple of potential workarounds:

1. Downgrade your package version to **apache-airflow-providers-amazon==2.3.0**. This may resolve the issue, but keep in mind that you might miss out on any new features or improvements introduced in the latest version.
2. Alternatively, you can create your own email backend to work around the problem. Here's a sample code snippet (emailer.py) that you can use:

```py
from typing import List, Optional, Union
from airflow.configuration import conf
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.ses import SESHook


def send_email(
    to: Union[List[str], str],
    subject: str,
    html_content: str,
    files: Optional[List] = None,
    cc: Optional[Union[List[str], str]] = None,
    bcc: Optional[Union[List[str], str]] = None,
    mime_subtype: str = 'mixed',
    mime_charset: str = 'utf-8',
    conn_id: str = None,
    **kwargs,
) -> None:
    """Email backend for SES"""
    hook = SESHook(aws_conn_id=conn_id)
    hook.send_email(
        mail_from=conf.get('smtp', 'SMTP_MAIL_FROM'),
        to=to,
        subject=subject,
        html_content=html_content,
        files=files,
        cc=cc,
        bcc=bcc,
        mime_subtype=mime_subtype,
        mime_charset=mime_charset,
    )
```

To implement this solution:

1. Place the `emailer.py` file in the `dags/ses_email_fix/` directory with an empty `__init__.py` file.
2. Modify the `email.email_backend` setting in your `airflow.cfg` file to use `ses_email_fix.emailer.send_email` as the backend. Also, make sure to set `email.smtp_mail_from`.
3. Alternatively, you can set an environment variable `AIRFLOW__EMAIL__EMAIL_BACKEND` to `ses_email_fix.emailer.send_email`. Make sure to set `AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_MAIL_FROM`.
4. Don't forget to add the `ses_email_fix` folder to your `.airflowignore` file to prevent Airflow from interpreting it as a DAG.