Setup MWAA send email using secret manager
I want to send email from MWAA workflows. I have seen that we can configure SMTP details in cfg file or we can override details using environments page.
But I want to use secret manager to store connection details.
Could someone please point me in the direction, how to use secret manager to store connection details and use it to send emails?
It is not necessary to use EmailOperator, if there is any other way of doing it, I am okay with that.
Thanks.

You could make use of the email.email_backend MWAA configuration option by providing a custom email_backend implementation. There you can make calls to SecretsManager using boto3 and populate the necessary configuration properties.
This article will get you started https://dev.to/mucio/aws-mwaa-and-aws-ses-integration-odg

You can find some implementation details in my answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/77230454/2996867
